# Macbook Pro with Windows 7 - GPU always on

Tags: windows-7, macbook, power-management, gpu

Übergizmo [is reporting](http://www.ubergizmo.com/15/archives/2010/04/macbook_pro_geforce_330m_always_on_in_windows_7.html) an issue with the new Macbook Pros' GeForce 330M GPU being always "on" under Windows 7, and thus almost halving the battery life compared to that with OS X (which is able to somehow suspend that GPU and use the lower-end integrated GPU to do the light work).

Any solutions, or rumors of coming solutions?

Comment: Actually, I think Windows 7 supports such a configuration as well, but it may depend on the drivers and thus this could be ultimately Apple's fault since they provide Windows drivers for Mac hardware, iirc.

Comment: It's quite likely Apple's fault. It would be easy to dismiss them if they were not making such nice hardware:)

Answer (score 1):

This has been a problem since MacBook-Pro's have come out with two GPUs. For now, Apple doesn't allow you to switch to the integrated GPU when using Windows. But then you're most likely to boot to Windows for stuff that needs a high-end GPU, anyway.